# SELECT statement to generate INSERT value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is is possible to  do this in SQL i.e. use a `SELECT` statement to generate an `INSERT` value:

```
insert into  [processing].dbinputfields ([description], fieldtypeid, datasetid)
values ('ID', + select id from [processing].dbfieldtype where description='URN' + ,6)
```

I know I could assign the value of ID to a variable (@ID).  However, I was wandering if it could be done like the SQL statement above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `insert select` statement in SQL Server.

Change your query to this:

```
insert into  [processing].dbinputfields ([description], fieldtypeid, datasetid)
select 'ID', id, 6
from [processing].dbfieldtype
where description = 'URN'
```